# call to expect utility is failing

Tags: shell, unix, expect

I'm calling a function in which I'm scp files to remote server. but its giving out error.

Function below :-

```
scp_files()
{     
######## scp  files to remote host ###############
echo "**************************************************************************"
echo "         scp  files to remote host               ..                      *"
echo "**************************************************************************"

echo "value of first argument is $1"
echo "silver username is  $silver_username"

expect <<- DONE
 log_user 0
 set timeout -1
 spawn scp commands.txt $silver_username@$1:/tmp/
 expect "password: "
 send "test123\r"
 expect "$ "
 send "exit\r"
expect eof
DONE 


}
```

#### calling  function

```
scp_files ${!REDIS_IP} ${!REDIS_PORT}
```

here im getting error as below :

> send: spawn id exp5 not open

Where could be the issue here?

Comment: #properties file
 markets=au,ca,uk
 silver_username=cmloperas

Comment: Just a guess: Since `exp5` is the handle, which expect uses to communicate to the process, the error message means that you try to send something, but the process is already terminated. I find your `expect "$ "` strange. I don't see why scp would send back a `$`. Do you get the error message immediately, or after several seconds? Has the file been copied? Also, I would always check the return value of `spawn` and send only something if the process was actually spawned. I don't think this is the cause of *your* error, but in general, it's a good idea.

Comment: BTW, if you have [sshpass](https://sourceforge.net/projects/sshpass/), or are OK with installing it, you can do it without expect.